# Trying to write raw PCM to WAV and only getting header

Tags: java, audio, encoding, wav, pcm

I am currently using this code:

```
File wavFile=new File("tmp"+File.separator+"recordings"+File.separator+uuid.toString()+".wav");
try{
    FileInputStream pcmInputStream=new FileInputStream(file);
    FileOutputStream wavOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(wavFile);
    AudioSystem.write(new AudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(IOUtils.toByteArray(pcmInputStream)),
    new AudioFormat(48000,16,2,true,
    true),IOUtils.toByteArray(pcmInputStream).length/4),
    AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,wavOutputStream);
    wavOutputStream.flush();
    wavOutputStream.close();
    pcmInputStream.close();
    fileOutputStream.close();
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Having checked, I can confirm that the PCM has 30 seconds of data and is approximately 4.7MB. This writes the .wav file however it is only 44 bytes and not playable, I reckon that this 44 bytes is the RIFF header but am unsure of how to solve it. I have tried using different lengths and different combinations of File/ByteArray OutputStreams.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java pcm to wav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440015/java-pcm-to-wav)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the `AudioInputStream`, you call `IOUtils.toByteArray(pcmInputStream)` twice, and on the second call, the input stream is already advanced to the end, so `toByteArray` returns an empty array. This results in 0 getting passed as the argument to the `AudioInputStream` constructor's length.

```
new AudioInputStream(
    new ByteArrayInputStream( IOUtils.toByteArray(pcmInputStream) ),
    new AudioFormat(48000,16,2,true,true),
    ( IOUtils.toByteArray(pcmInputStream) ).length/4
)
```

You should save the byte array to a temporary variable instead of trying to call `toByteArray` twice on the same input stream.